# adding multiple values of elem.attrib into a variable

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree

Started playing with Python and ElementTree very recently to acheive something quite specific. I am very nearly there I think but there is one thing that I can't quite work out. I am querying an xml file and pulling back the relevant data - then putting that data into a csv file. It all works but the issue is that the elem.attrib["text"] actually returns multiple lines - when I put it into a variable the variable and export to a csv it only exports the first line - below is the code I am using...

```
import os
import csv

import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

path = "/share/new"

c = csv.writer(open("/share/redacted.csv", "wb"))

c.writerow(["S","R","T","R2","R3"])


for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith('.xml'):
            fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
            tree = ET.ElementTree(file=(fullname))
            for elem in tree.iterfind('PropertyList/Property[@name="Sender"]'):
                    c1 = elem.attrib["value"]
            for elem in tree.iterfind('PropertyList/Property[@name="Recipient"]'):
                    c2 = elem.attrib["value"]
            for elem in tree.iterfind('PropertyList/Property[@name="Date"]'):
                    c3 = elem.attrib["value"]
            for elem in tree.iterfind('ChildContext/ResponseList/Response/TextualAnalysis/ExpressionList/Expression/Match'):
                    c4 = elem.attrib["textView"]
            for elem in tree.iterfind('ChildContext/ResponseList/Response/TextualAnalysis/ExpressionList/Expression/Match/Matched'):
                    c5 = elem.attrib["text"]
                    print elem.attrib["text"]
                    print c5
            c.writerow([(c1),(c2),(c3),(c4),(c5)])
```

The most important part is right near the bottom - the output of print elem.atrrib["text"] is:

```
Apples
Bananas
```

The output of 'print c5' is the same (just to be clear that is Apples and Bananas on seperate lines)

But, outputting c5 to a csv only outputs the first line and therefore only Apples appears in the csv.

I hope this makes sense - what I need to do is output both Apples and Bananas to the csv (in the same cell preferably). The below is in Python 2.7 in development but ideally I need it to work in 2.6 (I realise iterfind is not in 2.6 - I have 2 versions of code already)

I would post the xml but it is a bit of a beast. - As per suggestion in comments here is a cleaned up XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Context>
    <PropertyList duplicates="true">
        <Property name="Sender" type="string" value="S:demo1@no-one.local"/>
        <Property name="Recipient" type="string" value="RPFD:no-one.local"/>
        <Property name="Date" type="string" value="Tue, 4 Aug 2015 13:24:16 +0100"/>
    </PropertyList>
    <ChildContext>
        <ResponseList>
            <Response>
                <Description>
                    <Arg />
                    <Arg />
                </Description>
                <TextualAnalysis version="2.0">
                    <ExpressionList>
                        <Expression specified=".CLEAN.(Apples)" total="1" >
                            <Match textView="Body" truncated="false">
                                <Surrounding text="..."/>
                                <Surrounding text="How do you like them "/>
                                <Matched cleaned="true" text="Apples " type="expression"/>
                                <Surrounding text="???????? "/>
                                <Surrounding text="..."/>
                            </Match>
                        </Expression>
                    </ExpressionList>
                </TextualAnalysis>
            </Response>
        </ResponseList>
    </ChildContext>
    <ChildContext>
        <ResponseList>
            <Response>
                <Description>
                    <Arg />
                    <Arg />
                </Description>
                <TextualAnalysis version="2.0">
                    <ExpressionList>
                        <Expression specified=".CLEAN.(Bananas)" total="1" >
                            <Match textView="Attach" truncated="false">
                                <Surrounding text="..."/>
                                <Surrounding text="Also I don't like... "/>
                                <Matched cleaned="true" text="Bananas " type="expression"/>
                                <Surrounding text="!!!!!!! "/>
                                <Surrounding text="..."/>
                            </Match>
                        </Expression>
                    </ExpressionList>
                </TextualAnalysis>
            </Response>
        </ResponseList>
    </ChildContext>
</Context>
```

Comment: If the XML is a "beast", please provide a trimmed down version of it. It is hard to help without any XML to work with.

Comment: csv.writerow() will create a cell with linefeeds in it.  But there will be " at the beginning and at the end of that cell"  If you are not seeing that, then it may be because your print of c5 is not at the same level as your writerow.  For debugging, I would print(repr(c5)) at the same indentation level as the writerow...

Comment: @PatrickMaupin - thanks, that's useful. I have tried the command you suggested... running the print(repr(c5)) at the same indentation as writerow returns 'Apples '. Running the same command at the same indentation as c5 = elem.attrib["text"] returns 'Apples ' 'Bananas ' (on seperate lines). Running the csv.writerow command at that same indentation level writes 2 rows to the csv, c1,c2,c3,c4 are repeated, and c5 has a different value on each line (Apples and Bananas). Unfortunately I need to do the same for c4... Any ideas?

Comment: @mzjn Good point, I have added a trimmed down xml

Comment: That says that 'apples' and 'bananas' are not in the same XML element.  Do you want one line per file?  If so, you need to make C5 a list and append them to it.  If you want one line per element, then you need to put the writerow inside your for loop (and maybe even nest your for-loops, depending on what you want.)

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Thanks for your help so far. Really I would really like 1 line per file if possible - how do I go about making c5 a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will join together all the text elements, and put them on separate lines *in the same cell* inside your CSV.  You can change the '\n' separator to ' ' or ',' to put them on the same line.  *However*, you might still have issues with some of your other stuff -- you don't have nested loops there and I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish, so maybe you have more than one of each of those other things too.  Anyway:

```
        c5 = []
        for elem in tree.iterfind('ChildContext/ResponseList/Response/TextualAnalysis/ExpressionList/Expression/Match/Matched'):
                c5.append(elem.attrib["text"])
        c.writerow([c1, c2, c3, c4, '\n'.join(c5)])
```

Comment: Fantastic thanks, that achieves what I need to do - it was really a case of getting all of the c5 values out and that has accomplished it.